# How can I getsize different files in a listdir?

Tags: python

I seem to be only able to find the "getsize" of my entire directory, instead of the individual files in the directory <= 64 bytes.  Any ideas or suggestions would be really appreciated, thank you!

Here is my script:

```
#argument is directory path

import os, sys 

myDir = sys.argv[1]
myFiles = os.listdir(myDir)

for eachOne in myFiles:
    size = os.path.getsize(myFiles)
    if size <= "64":
       print "{0} is {1} bytes.".format(eachOne, size)
```

The goal is to print out the file name is XX bytes.

Comment: Don't you mean `os.path.getsize(eachOne)`?

Comment: @larsks you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Eh, I'm good.  iCodez has elaborated on it sufficiently than another answer would just be quibbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems here:

1. You need to give [`os.path.getsize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) `eachOne` instead of `myFiles`.
2. `os.path.getsize` returns an integer.  Meaning, you need to compare `size` with another integer, not a string.
3. You need to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to give `os.path.getsize` the full path to the file.  Otherwise, Python will not know where the file is.

Below is a version of your script with these problems addressed:

```
import os, sys 

myDir = sys.argv[1]
myFiles = os.listdir(myDir)

for eachOne in myFiles:
    size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(myDir, eachOne))
    if size <= 64:
       print "{0} is {1} bytes.".format(eachOne, size)
```

Comment: this worked for me - I used concatenation instead of join.  But you are right about I needed the full path name & the size to not be a string.  I appreciate the help very much.